# C# Errors and Headache >.< (MonoDevelop version2.8.2 for Unity 3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I have a problem :/ first off Im using C#.. Next, in the section where you see

```
public int BaseValue()
    {
 get{return _basevalue;}
 set{_basevalue value; }
 }
```

I get 3 Errors

1) Unexpected symbol `{'

2)Unexpected symbol `{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

and

3) Parsing Error

and frankly its pissing me off -_- so does anyone know what the problem may be?

---

```
public class BaseStats {

private int _basevalue; //base value of this stat
private int _buffvalue; //amount needed to buff the stat
private int _expToLevel; //amount needed to move to the next level
private float _LevelModifier; //the modifier applied to the exp needed to raise the skill


public BaseStats()
{
_basevalue = 0;
_buffvalue = 0;
_expToLevel = 100;
_LevelModifier = 1.1f;
}


//Basic Setters and Getters
public int BaseValue()
{
get{return _basevalue;}
set{_basevalue value; }
}

public int BuffValue()
{
get{return _buffvalue; }
set{_buffvalue value; }
}

public int ExpToLevel()
{
get{return _expToLevel; }
set{_expToLevel.value; }
}

public float LevelModifier()
{
get{return _levelModifier; }
set{_levelModifier.value; }
}

private int CalculateExpToLevel()
{
return (int)(_expToLevel * _levelModifier);
}

public void LevelUp()
{
_expToLevel = CalculateExpToLevel();
_baseValue++;
}

public int AdjustedValue()
{
return _baseValue + _buffValue;
}



}
```

---

Comment: All your `sets` are wrong. They should be: `_basevalue = value;` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties do not have parentheses. Eliminate the () and fix your setter on what you intend to be properties. Eliminate the get/set on what you intend to be methods.

```
// this is a property 
public int Foo
{
     get { return foo; }
     set { foo = value; }
}

// this is a method 
public decimal Bar()
{
    // do something and return a decimal
}
```

And note, as of C# 3, if your property is a simple get/set operation, you can use auto-implemented properties and eliminate the explicit backing variable.

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```